# Using linq, database doesn't have FK relations to tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a database that has primary key fields in its tables, but the FK mappings are not in place.

What are the ramifications of this when using linq-to-sql?

Answer (score 1):

FK Mappings?  You mean FK Constraints...

Without FK Constraints, you are allowed to create orphan'd data.  You can create an Order child) for which there is no Customer (parent).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the generator to create your LINQ-to-SQL classes - or rather you can, but they won't have any associations in them. However, I do not think that it actually cares about FK, so if you write the classes yourself, or modify the generated classes, to use `EntitySet` properties with `[Association]` attributes as [described in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386950.aspx), you shouldn't have any problems.